# How to calculate age in years based on Date of Birth in different calendar?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, date, select

I've two names in database table:

- **decease_date**
- **birth_date**

I've set birth day calculation based on these two names value in sql table, here is the code:

```
$sql .= "FLOOR((TO_DAYS(GREATEST(IF(decease_date='0000-00-00',CURRENT_DATE,decease_date),IFNULL(decease_date,CURRENT_DATE))) - TO_DAYS(birth_date)) / 365) AS age";
```

and I've set localDate to another calendar which is Persian Calendar through [jDateTime](https://github.com/sallar/jDateTime/blob/master/jdatetime.class.php) method:

here is the code:

```
public static function localDate($date = "")
  {$local = "";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
switch (strlen($date))
{default: // Ymd
      {
      if (( $date < '19700101'))
      {
     $local = $date;
     break;
      }
      else
      {
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/jdatetime.class.php';
        $local = jDateTime::date("l j F Y", strtotime($date), true, true, 'Asia/Tehran');
        break;}
    }
    break;}
return $local;}
```

**The problem is *CURRENT_DATE* in sql that it will calculate current date based on Gregorian Calendar not *CURRENT_DATE* in Persian Calendar.**

That's why when we set Birth Day in Gregorian calendar and Persian Calendar, my code will calculate **Patient Age** based on Gregorian calendar.

This is sample of calculation in two different calendar date:

[image]

> Q: How to set Current Date in SQL based on Persian Calendar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use CURRENT_DATE in your SQL, you could do

```
$persian_current_date = jDateTime::date("Y-m-d", false, true, true, 'Asia/Tehran');
$sql .= "FLOOR((TO_DAYS(GREATEST(IF(decease_date='0000-00-00','$persian_current_date',decease_date),IFNULL(decease_date,'$persian_current_date)))) - TO_DAYS(birth_date)) / 365) AS age";
```

Better yet, just select the person's birthday and deceased date, and do your calculation in PHP, which allows you to use a method of calculating age other than DAYS / 365 (which fails to account for leap years).

Comment: I tried your way, I got error: Unable to execute query.